# How to set a tag ID when exporting Excel to XML?

Tags: xml, excel

I have a very simple, three-column excel file:

[image]

I would like to export it to an XML file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<translations>
<item id="USER_NAME">
    <en>Username</en>
    <de>Username_D</de>
</item>
<item id="PASSWORD">
    <en>Password</en>
    <de>Password_D</de>
</item>
</translations>
```

I only managed to use the following mapping file so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="translations">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="item" id="pippo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="en" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="de" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Which almost gives what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<translations>
<item>
    <en>Username</en>
    <de>Username_D</de>
</item>
<item>
    <en>Password</en>
    <de>Password_D</de>
</item>
</translations>
```

How do I set the id field into the idem node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found a workaround.

I create an XML like this (i.e. resembling the final result)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<translations xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<item id="USER_NAME">
    <en>Username</en>
    <de>Username_D</de>
</item>
<item id="PASSWORD">
    <en>Password</en>
    <de>Password_D</de>
</item>
</translations>
```

Import the XML into Excel via the Developer tab.
Drag it to a new spreadsheet so that I have a new XML-based Excel sheet.
Copy/paste all the values I need and export.
So, for example, this sheet

[image]

will produce this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<translations xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<item id="USER_NAME">
    <en>Username</en>
    <de>Username_D</de>
</item>
<item id="PASSWORD">
    <en>Password</en>
    <de>Password_D</de>
</item>
<item id="SOME">
    <en>A</en>
    <de>B</de>
</item>
</translations>
```

Comment: Very straightforward, although might be an option))) +1 for clever trick!