# adding an attribute to xml tags before exporting the file from excel 2010 to use with mantis

Tags: xml, excel, xsd, mantis

i'm using mantis and i need to import my bugs written on excel spreadsheet to mantis,so i created a schema(file.xsd) and mapped my data to that schema and finally i exported my bugs into xml file that is compatible with mantis.the problem is i need to add an attribute(id) to certain tags in the produced xml file, is there any way to do that step (e.g add a column in excel for instance) during the file preparation, i mean before exporting the file?
here is an example of the data exported and the data i want it to look like:

the exported data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mantis version="1.2.12" urlbase="http:xxx/mantis/" issuelink="#"  notelink="~" format="1">
<issue>
    <id>29</id>

    <project>Project 1</project>

    <reporter>Engy</reporter>

    <priority>urgent</priority>

    <severity>block</severity>

   <reproducibility>always</reproducibility>

    <status>new</status>

    <resolution>open</resolution>

    <projectio>none</projection>
   </issue>
 </mantis>
```

i need to add id attribute to `<project>` and `<priority>` and `<severity>`:

```
 <project id="1">project 1</project>
 .
 .
```

Comment: Please look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14724334/1953175

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a tag ID when exporting Excel to XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724098/how-to-set-a-tag-id-when-exporting-excel-to-xml)